# 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll' error message in Beautiful Soup within a function

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

I am learning Pyhton and beautiful soup in particular and I am doing the Google Exercise on Regex using the set of html files that contains popular baby names for different years (e.g. baby1990.html etc).  You can find this dataset if you are interested here: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/baby-names

Each html file contains a table with baby names data that looks like this:

[image]

I have composed a function that extracts the baby names from the html files and stores them to dataframes, the dataframes in a dictionary and all the dataframes aggregated in a single dataframe.

There are two tables in each html file.  The table that contains the baby data has the following html code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" summary="formatting">
```

In this line the distinctive attribute is the summary = "formatting".

The function I wrote was edited based on feedback I received and is the following:

```
def babynames(path):

# This function takes the path of the directory where the html files are stored and returns a list containing the 
# a dataframe which encompasses all the tabular baby-names data in the files and as well as a dictionary holding
# a separate dataframe for each html file

# 0: Initialize objects
dicnames = {}  # will hold the dataframes containing the tabular data of each year
dfnames = pd.DataFrame([])  # will hold the aggregate data

# 1: Create a list containing the full paths of the baby files in the directory indicated by the path argument of the babynames
# function
allfiles = files(path)

# 2: Begin the looping through the files 

for file in allfiles: 
        with open(file,"r") as f: soup = bs(f.read(), 'lxml')  # Convert the file to a soup

        # 3. Initialize empty lists to hold the contents of the cells
        Rank=[]
        Baby_1 =[]
        Baby_2 =[] 
        df = pd.DataFrame([])

        # 4. Extract the Table containing the Baby data and loop through the rows of this table

        for row in soup.select("table[summary=formatting] tr"):

         # 5. Extract the cells 

            cells = row.findAll("td")

            # 6. Convert to text and append to lists
            try:
                Rank.append(cells[0].find(text=True))  
                Baby_1.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
                Baby_2.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
            except:
                print "file: " , file
                try:
                        print "cells[0]: " , cells[0]
                except:
                        print "cells[0] : NaN"
                try:
                        print "cells[1]: " , cells[1]
                except:
                        print "cells[1] : NaN"    
                try:
                        print "cells[2]: " , cells[2]
                except:
                        print "cells[2] : NaN"   

            # 7. Append the lists to the empty dataframe df
            df["Rank"] = Rank 
            df["Baby_1"] = Baby_1
            df["Baby_2"] = Baby_2

            # 8. Append the year to the dataframe as a separate column
            df["Year"] = extractyear(file)  # Call the function extractyear() defined in the environment with input
                                            # the full pathname stored in variable file and examined in the current
                                            # iteration

            # 9. Rearrange the order of columns
            # df.columns.tolist() = ['Year', 'Rank', 'Baby_1', 'Baby_2']

            #10. Store the dataframe to a dictionary as the value which key is the name of the file
            pattern = re.compile(r'.*(baby\d\d\d\d).*')
            filename = re.search(pattern, file).group(1)
            dicnames[filename] = df

    # 11. Combine the dataframes stored in the dictionary dicname to an aggregate dataframe dfnames
        for key, value in dicnames.iteritems():
             dfnames = pd.concat[dfnames, value] 

    # 12. Store the dfnames and dicname in a list called result.  Return result.
        result = [dfnames, dicnames]
        return result
```

When I run the function with a given path (the path of my directory where I have stored the html files) I get the following error message:

```
result = babynames(path)
```

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


file:  C:/Users/ALEX/MyFiles/JUPYTER NOTEBOOKS/google-python-exercises/babynames/baby1990.html
cells[0]:  cells[0] : NaN
cells[1]:  cells[1] : NaN
cells[2]:  cells[2] : NaN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-5c9ebdc4dcdb> in <module>()
----> 1 result = babynames(path)

<ipython-input-71-a0263a6790da> in babynames(path)
     54 
     55                 # 7. Append the lists to the empty dataframe df
---> 56                 df["Rank"] = Rank
     57                 df["Baby_1"] = Baby_1
     58                 df["Baby_2"] = Baby_2

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2355         else:
   2356             # set column
-> 2357             self._set_item(key, value)
   2358 
   2359     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2421 
   2422         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2423         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   2424         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2425 

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _sanitize_column(self, key, value)
   2576 
   2577             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2578             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   2579             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   2580                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   2768 
   2769     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 2770         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   2771 
   2772     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

The cells[0], cells[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF3ef.png) and cells[2] should have values.

As I mentioned there is one more table preceding identified by the following html code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
```

I have run a version of the function where I did not specify the table -- I had not observed that there were two tables in the html file.  In that version I did not get this type of error.  I had error messages for line 6 that identation of try statements was not proper -- which I do not understand-- and error message for line 9 where I attempt to rearrange the columns of the dataframe -- which I also could not understand.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: try `right_table.find_all("tr")`. Replace `findAll()` with `find_all()`

Answer (score 2):

`right_table` is a `ResultSet` instance (basically, a list of `Tag` instances representing elements), it does not have `findAll()` or `find_all()` method.

Instead, you either loop over elements in `right_table` if you've got multiple of them:

```
right_table = soup.find_all("table", summary_ = "formatting")

for table in right_table:
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        # ...
```

Or, use `find()` in case there is a single one:

```
right_table = soup.find("table", summary_ = "formatting")
```

Or, use a single *CSS selector*:

```
for row in soup.select("table[summary=formatting] tr"):
    # ...
```